# Windows Error: errors happened while running xgettext on __init__.py ,'xgettext' is not recognizad as an internal or external command

Tags: python, django

when running `django-admin.py makemessages -l fa` based on internationalization documentations in windows i get this error:

```
Windows Error: errors happened while running xgettext on __init__.py ,'xgettext' is not recognizad as an internal or external command
```

what should I install and which variables add to environment?I googled alot but just found a japanese references!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/#gettext-on-windows).

Comment: I downloaded both of them(gettext-runtime-X.zip,gettext-tools-X.zip
) and extracted their bin folder contents ino this path:C:\Program Files\gettext-utils\bin and added this path to system path.but I have the same problem

Comment: I downloaded it's Installation version from this address and it worked : http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/gettext/0.14.4/gettext-0.14.4.exe/download

Comment: Link not working anymore (404)